# When a process is in uninterruptible sleep state (D), does it count into cumulative time of the output from "top" command?

Tags: linux

I have researched this - there are several related questions/answers. However, I couldn't find a definitive answer for this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> When 'Cumulative time' mode is On, each process is listed with the cpu
>   time that it and its dead children have used.

In case your question refers to the parent process, it of course is integrated into the CPU time, albeit it uses no additional time while it sleeps.
In case your question refers to a child process, it is not (yet) integrated into the CPU time, because it is not dead.